# Repeater in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm using Gravity Forms, and I need the repeater for some fields(including data, checkbox, radio buttons.. so the default List field is not suitable for me). I found Gravity Forms Repeater Add-On plugin that does exactly what I want, but this plugin doesn't support ajax. Do someone have any idea how to fix this, or maybe recommend another plugin for this.

Answer (score 2):

Gravity Forms 2.4 introduces an API for adding repeaters via a PHP configuration. It's pretty straightforward but not feature rich just yet.

https://docs.gravityforms.com/repeater-fields/

If you're looking for a repeater solution that doesn't require touching any code, check out my Gravity Forms Nested Forms plugin.

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-nested-forms/